# Problem on how to display members info from a database with mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay I have a piece of code that for some reason gives me the following errors.

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in
```

here is the code below.

```
$dbc = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM sitename WHERE id='$user_id'"); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)){ 
$state = $row["state"];
$city = $row["city"];
$zip = $row["zip"]; 
$bio_body = $row["bio_body"];
```

If you can please help me by giving me the correct code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqli\_query expects at least 2 parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073278/mysqli-query-expects-at-least-2-parameters)

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the database link parameter as well as the query you want to run.  Like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM sitename WHERE id='$user_id'");
```

I don't see why it wouldn't work after that's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_query expects a link identifier from the database as the first argument, which is returned by mysqli_connect.

this causing the query to get a null result, which is causing the second error.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP builder](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/function.mysqli-query.php):

> Description
>
> Procedural style: mixed mysqli_query (
>   mysqli link, string query [, int
>   resultmode] )

This basically means you are missing one parameter, the link you create when you open the database connection. Take a look at the following example:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$dbc = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM sitename WHERE id='$user_id'");
```

mysqli_fetch_array doesn't work because the previous command failed.