# mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, mysqli

This `mysqli_query` command results in the error below

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `counter`.`hits` (`page_hits`) VALUES (1)");
```

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

What does this error message mean, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: http://php.net/mysqli_query has the answer (you need to specify the link explicitly when you use the mysqli functions)

Comment: note that constructing a query like this WILL open your server to SQL injection, which might be enough for a even a script kiddie to hack your server and steal passwords / use it as part of botnet / anything else they want to

Answer (score 22):

You need to specify the connection that you made to your database somewhere earlier in your page. You should put that variable in the query. Suppose you made a variable called `$con`. Then your code should be like this.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `counter`.`hits` (`page_hits`) VALUES (1)");
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query)

```
Procedural style

mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

You'll notice the `$link` and `$query` variables.

This means that you need to pass the function a valid mysqli link resource as well as the query you wish to perform. This lets the function know which established connection to the server to use.

A link resource can be created using:

> Procedural style only: A link identifier returned by mysqli_connect()
> or mysqli_init()

and an example of how to do so can be found on the aforementioned manual page.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are confusing mysql_query with mysqli_query. The former accepts the sql statement as the first param, while the latter expects a link identifier (created by Mysqli::connect) as the first param and the statement as the second.

The two extensions are not compatable with each other. I suggest you pick one, read the manual pages on how to connect, execute queries, etc, and forget the other exists. which one you pick is up to you, mysqli is more feature rich but more complicated as a result.

Answer (score 3):

If you get any of the following errors:

> mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given
>
> mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters
>
> mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters

It means that you have not passed the mandatory parameter to these functions. MySQLi procedural style functions expect the first parameter to be a valid MySQLi connection link.

For example, [`mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) expects a database link as the first argument and the actual SQL query as a second argument.

Assuming you have this or similar connection code somewhere at the start of you script.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
mysqli_set_charset ($mysqli, 'utf8mb4');
```

You can use the connection link saved in `$mysqli` and pass it as a first argument.

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `counter`.`hits` (`page_hits`) VALUES (1)");
```

Most of the mysqli procedural functions require the connection to be passed as an argument. However, a simpler option would be to switch to Object-oriented style. In OOP you call the method on the object passing only the SQL as a single argument.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `counter`.`hits` (`page_hits`) VALUES (1)");
```

**Warning!**

You should be using parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. `mysqli_query()` should only be utilized when you are not passing any inputs to your SQL. Whenever you want to pass inputs, as is the case with `INSERT` for example, you must use parameter binding. You can replace you `mysqli_query()` call with:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `counter`.`hits` (`page_hits`) VALUES (?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $hits);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query` excepts 2 parameters, the first variable is `mysqli_connect` equivalent variable, the second one is the query you have provided

```
$name1 = mysqli_connect(localhost,db_username ,db_pswd ,db_name );

$name2 = mysqli_query($name1,"INSERT INTO `counter`.`hits` (`page_hits`) VALUES (1)");
```