# converting mysql into mysqli check for query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have a select query. another short if-form checks if this select query returns something or not.

so i have:

```
$query = "SELECT `a` FROM `b` WHERE c='$c'";
$test = ($query = mysql_query($query)) ? $mysql_num_rows($query) : 0;
```

so i would like to convert into mysqli but the following code seems to be wrong ($db = mysqli):

```
$query = "SELECT `a` FROM `b` WHERE c='$c'";
$test = ($query = $db->query($query)) ? $db->num_rows($query) : 0;
```

when using:

```
$test = ($query = mysqli_query($query)) ? mysqli_num_rows($query) : 0;
```

it will echo the error message:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given...
```

so if there is someone who would be that friendly and could give me an advise to solve this i really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

Comment: `$mysql_num_rows(...)` is a typo, I'm assuming? Variable functions are about as scary as variable variables.

Comment: Did you instantiate the $db class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqli\_query expects at least 2 parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073278/mysqli-query-expects-at-least-2-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqli in procedural mode doesn't default to using the last-established connection like the mysql library does. You have to explicitly include the connection each time:

```
$test = ($query = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) ? mysqli_num_rows($query) : 0;
                               ^^^^^^
```

As well, for num_rows, it's `mysqli_stmt_num_rows($result)`

Comment: using this echos: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given // $db = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

Comment: well, yeah, you have to pass in whatever var you're using for the mysqli connection handle... That'd be whatever was returned from mysqli_connect()

Comment: sorry, i'm having understanding problems. what does that exactly mean? thanks.

Comment: okay as i get it, this errormessage will say that $db is not given. but, $db is $db = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world")

Comment: hmm... i forgot to say that this happens in a function so that i had to set global $db. thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: "mysqli in procedural mode doesn't default to using the last-established connection like the mysql library does."
It's a pain but an obligation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the procedural style (i.e. mysqli_query instead of OO approach), then you should add the $link var to your parameters of the [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)