# html data to array for mySQL insertion

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a list of HTML data which i would like to have inserted into a mySQL database.

I'm sort of a beginner on this one so I need some help in how to convert the HTML data toward an array, and insert that data into a mySQL database.

The html data looks like this:

```
<tr><td></td>
<td class="plannedtime" align="right">09:00</td>
<td><a href="./draw.aspx?id=406FB89A-DCD9-409B-AB32-033677CFAEC8&amp;draw=111">groep 1 - boys U19 - finale 17-24 A</a></td><td class="nowrap" align="right"><a class="teamname" href="team.aspx?id=406FB89A-DCD9-409B-AB32-033677CFAEC8&amp;team=3">Home Team</a><img src="//static.tournamentsoftware.com/images/flags/16/NED.png" class="intext flag" alt="Nederland" title="Nederland" height="14" width="16"><span class="printonly flag">[NED] </span></td>
<td align="center">-</td>
<td class="nowrap"><img src="//static.tournamentsoftware.com/images/flags/16/NED.png" class="intext flag" alt="Nederland" title="Nederland" height="14" width="16"><span class="printonly flag">[NED] </span><strong><a class="teamname" href="team.aspx?id=406FB89A-DCD9-409B-AB32-033677CFAEC8&amp;team=15">Away Team</a></strong></td>
<td><span class="score"><span>0-4</span></span></td>
<td><a href="./court.aspx?id=406FB89A-DCD9-409B-AB32-033677CFAEC8&amp;crtid=65">Pitch 3a</a>
</td></tr>
```

I think i should extraxt the data with a for loop and put it into an array.

this is the data i need from the html above:

Time - schedule - home - away - homegoals - awaygoals -pitch

Who can help me on building an array, and help me on how to inset this into a database with colums like below:

Time - schedule - home - away - homegoals - awaygoals -pitch

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
I have used the stripttags functionality to end up with a complete list of information like this:

strip_tags($table);

```
Wedstrijdoverzicht van zondag 20 april 2014 TijdstipSchemaUitslagVeld 09:00groep 1 - boys U19 - finale 17-24 AFC Lisse[NED] -[NED] Hapse Boys0-4Cuijk - veld 3a 09:00groep 1 - boys U19 - finale 17-24 BVV Gesta[NED] -[NED] RKSV Odiliapeel/Braks0-4Cuijk - veld 1a 09:00groep 1 - boys U19 - finale 17-24 BWVV Constantia[NED] -[ENG] The Cardinal Vaughan 21-3Cuijk - veld 2a 09:00groep 2 - boys U17 - finale 1 09-12KFC Werchter[BEL] -[GER] Salamanda Kornwestheim1-0Wanroij - veld 1a 09:00groep 2 - boys U17 - finale 1 09-12Broomhill[SCO] -[NED] Hapse Boys1-1Wanroij - veld 2a 09:00groep 2 - boys U17 - finale 1 13-16WVV Constantia[NED] -[NED] Voorschoten '972-3Wanroij - veld 3a 09:00groep 2 - boys U17 - finale 1 13-16Advanced Soccer Acedemy[LIB] -[NED] Neerlandia '310-0Wanroij - veld 4a 09:00groep 5.2 - boys U15 B - finale 17-24 AToxandria[NED] -[NED] Montagnards1-5Rijkevoort - veld 3a 09:00groep 5.2 - boys U15 B - finale 17-24 BBryrup IF[DEN] -[USA] Stuttgart Select7-0Rijkevoort - veld 1a 09:00groep 5.2 - boys U15 B - finale 17-24 BSv Zulte Waregem[BEL] -[ENG] Essex Royals WFC6-0Rijkevoort - veld 2a 09:00groep 3 - boys U16 - finale 13-16VV De Zwaluw[NED] -[NED] Sv Houten1-3Gennep - veld 1a 09:00groep 3 - boys U16 - finale 13-16Dosko '32[NED] -[NED] Blauw Wit '812-1Gennep - veld 2a 09:00groep 4 - boys U15 A - finale 13-16RKSV Mulo[NED] -[DEN] Snekkersten IF1-1Landhorst - veld 1a 09:00groep 4 - boys U15 A - finale 13-16FC Akilles[FIN] -[NED] Berghem Sport0-0Landhorst - veld 2a 09:00groep 5.1 - boys U15 B - finale 13-16Excellent[NED] -[ENG] St Edmundton Campain0-3Oploo - veld 1a 09:00groep 5.1 - boys U15 B - finale 13-16Bournemouth Collegiate[ENG] -[NED] Nooit Gedacht7-0Oploo - veld 2a 09:00groep 6 - boys U14 A - finale 13-16WVV Constantia[NED] -[DEN] Stautrup IF0-3Beugen - veld 1a 09:00groep 6 - boys U14 A - finale 13-16MK Dons SET FC[ENG] -[ENG] Welling FC1-1Beugen - veld 2a 09:00groep 7.1 - boys U14 B - finale 13-16VV De Willy's[NED] -[WAL] Penrhyn Bay FC1-1Wilbertoord - veld 1a 09:00groep 7.1 - boys U14 B - finale 13-16Slagelse B&I[DEN] -[NED] RKSV Volkel2-0Wilbertoord - veld 2a 09:00groep 7.2 - boys U14 B - fina
```

But I'm not sure how to extract the information I need from the $table variable above.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

So, just left the striptags aside.Now i've got the following result:

```
object(DOMElement)#1 (18) { ["tagName"]=> string(5) "table" ["schemaTypeInfo"]=> NULL ["nodeName"]=> string(5) "table" ["nodeValue"]=> string(78208) " Wedstrijdoverzicht van zondag 20 april 2014 TijdstipSchemaUitslagVeld 09:00groep 1 - boys U19 - finale 17-24 AFC Lisse[NED] -[NED] Hapse Boys0-4Cuijk - veld 3a 09:00groep 1 - boys U19 - finale 17-24 BVV Gesta[NED] -[NED] RKSV Odiliapeel/Braks0-4Cuijk - veld 1a 09:00groep 1 - boys U19 - finale 17-24 BWVV Constantia[NED] -[ENG] The Cardinal Vaughan 21-3Cuijk - veld 2a 09:00groep 2 - boys U17 - finale 1 09-12KFC Werchter[BEL] -[GER] Salamanda Kornwestheim1-0Wanroij - veld 1a 09:00groep 2 - boys U17 - finale 1 09-12Broomhill[SCO] -[NED] Hapse Boys1-1Wanroij - veld 2a 09:00groep 2 - boys U17 - finale 1 13-16WVV Constantia[NED] -[NED] Voorschoten '972-3Wanroij - veld 3a 09:00groep 2 - boys U17 - finale 1 13-16Advanced Soccer Acedemy[LIB] -[NED] Neerlandia '310-0Wanroij - veld 4a 09:00groep 5.2 - boys U15 B - finale 17-24 AToxandria[NED] -[NED] Montagnards1-5Rijkevoort - veld 3a 09:00groep 5.2 - boys U15 B - finale 17-24 BBryrup IF[DEN] -[USA] Stuttgart Select7-0Rijkevoort - veld 1a 09:00groep 5.2 - boys U15 B - finale 17-24 BSv Zulte Waregem[BEL] -[ENG] Essex Royals WFC6-0Rijkevoort - veld 2a 09:00groep 3 - boys U16 - finale 13-16VV De Zwaluw[NED] -[NED] Sv Houten1-3Gennep - veld 1a 09:00groep 3 - boys U16 - finale 13-16Dosko '32[NED] -[NED] Blauw Wit '812-1Gennep - veld 2a 09:00groep 4 - boys U15 A - finale 13-16RKSV Mulo[NED] -[DEN] Snekkersten IF1-1Landhorst - veld 1a 09:00groep 4 - boys U15 A - finale 13-16FC Akilles[FIN] -[NED] Berghem Sport0-0Landhorst - veld 2a 09:00groep 5.1 - boys U15 B - finale 13-16Excellent[NED] -[ENG] St Edmundton Campain0-3Oploo - veld 1a 09:00groep 5.1 - boys U15 B - finale 13-16Bournemouth Collegiate[ENG] -[NED] Nooit Gedacht7-0Oploo - veld 2a 09:00groep 6 - boys U14 A - finale 13-16WVV Constantia[NED] -[DEN] Stautrup IF0-3Beugen - veld 1a 09:00groep 6 - boys U14 A - finale 13-16MK Dons SET FC[ENG] -[ENG]
```

Now i Should know how to convert this to an array for mysql insertion

Comment: Have you actually tried coding any of it? Plenty of answers on the web, [for instance](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_insert_php.htm)

Comment: Hi @gudthing , yes i'm working on it as we speak. but having difficulties on creating the array from the HTML posted above and filtering out the html, and the information i don't need

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do (if I've understood you correctly) is create a link to your database

```
<?php
link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","table");

mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE(Time, schedule, 
      home, away, homegoals, awaygoals, pitch)

VALUES ($emp_time, $emp_schedule, $emp_home, $emp_away, 
        $emp_homegoals, $emp_awaygoals, $emp_pitch)") 
or die(mysqli_error($link));
?>
```

Where `$emp_time` is the table data `name` attribute and add `name` to all other `td` row to match the code.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835753/inserting-data-to-table-mysqli-insert)