# Call to a member function insert() on null WORDPRESS

Tags: php, mysql, plugins, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin for wordpress. I just finished my admin page. It has a submit button. The action attribute of form element is sending to "database.php" file.

Here's the code of database.php:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

        $table_name =  $wpdb->prefix . "ArmPoll_Questions";
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
    {

        $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('id'=>'','Question'=>'How r u?'));

    }
?>
```

But it leads to an error which says

> Call to a member function insert() on null

Answer (score 1):

You can't just write a straight up PHP page and expect it to work. You need to write this as a plugin or something that works within the framework of Wordpress. The error you're getting is that the [$wpdb object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) isn't defined. If you write it as a plugin `$wpdb` will be defined for you automatically.

[How to Write a Wordpress Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)

The other alternative is to open your own MySQL connection and do the insertion directly that way.

[How to insert data using mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835753/inserting-data-to-table-mysqli-insert)

Answer (score 0):

You can load core features where wpdb is defined with

```
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
require( BASE_PROY_ROOT.'/wp-load.php' );
```

The SHORTINIT set to "true" if for load only the basic of WP CORE.
Then you can use 
global $wpdb;