# Increment a value using msqli and php

Tags: php, mysql

I've database with a score. It starts of as 0 and when I press a button it should change to 1 on top of that number. If it was 7 it would then be 8. `

**This is the file which when you click the link it would take you to**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","score");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
session_start();
$id=$_SESSION['id'];


// Perform queries 
mysql_query($con,"
    UPDATE all_scores
    SET score1 = score1 + 1
    WHERE id = '".$id."'
")or die(mysql_error());

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This code should update the number from 0 to 1 or 1 to 2 depending on what number is on the database. My database name is scores. The table is all_scores the row numbers are listed as id and what I need updated is score1. The row that it updates depends on the id classified in the session as you can see. Please help. It doesn't update into my database.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: please post clear content with your problems , by the way you should pay more attention to post your question, if not you will be deleted with your question , meanwhile I got the message for the system ,the info is "Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully"

Comment: my code should make it update to 1 number higher then what is in the database but it doesnt @Strawberry

Comment: @jhkhhkhkkhhkhk are you sure that id exist ? echo statement and try to run in mysql console

Comment: You have a mysqli connection but a mysql query. That's not going to work

Comment: the id does exist. @FastSnail

Comment: @Strawberry how am i suppose to do it then

Comment: @jhkhhkhkkhhkhk use `mysqli` mysql is depreciated.don't mix both.use `mysqli_query` also `mysqli_error`.

Comment: please show me how i can do it i cant find it anywere @FastSnail

Comment: @jhkhhkhkkhhkhk see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835753/inserting-data-to-table-mysqli-insert and you can find lot of online tutorials.avoid mysql use mysqli

Comment: @FastSnail thanks iill try to use msqli

Comment: @jhkhhkhkkhhkhk also this manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.

Comment: all fixed thanks very much. @FastSnail