# MYSQL insertion using PHP prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to insert a row in mysql table using the below php prepared statement, but the code always pass the statement and move to echo "failed". what is missing in the below code?

(My Database has extra columns but I didn't add it as I don't want to insert values inside (one of these columns are auto increment))

```
<?php
    $ActivityDate = $_POST["ActivitytDate"];
    $CoreSite = $_POST["CoreSite"];
    $ActionAuditor = $_POST["ActionAuditor"];
    $DCOSPOC = $_POST["DCOSPOC"];

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Insert INTO DCO_Database (ActivityDate, CoreSite, ActionAuditor, DCOSPOC) Where (ActivityDate=? AND CoreSite=? AND ActionAuditor=? AND DCOSPOC=?)"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $ActivityDate, $CoreSite, $ActionAuditor, $DCOSPOC);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else{
        echo ("Failed");
        $mysqli->close();    
    }
?>
```

I have editied the code to use values instead, it is not echoing Failed but echoing success .. but still not adding values to database

```
<?php
$ActivityDate = $_POST["ActivitytDate"];
$CoreSite = $_POST["CoreSite"];
$ActionAuditor = $_POST["ActionAuditor"];
$DCOSPOC = $_POST["DCOSPOC"];
$AreaOwner = $_POST["AreaOwner"];
$ActionImplementer = $_POST["ActionImplementer"];
$ActionOwner = $_POST["ActionOwner"];
$MailSubject = $_POST["MailSubject"];
$ActionType = $_POST["ActionType"];
$RequestType = $_POST["RequestType"];
$RequestNumber = $_POST["RequestNumber"];
$OpenTime = $_POST["OpenTime"];
$CloseTime = $_POST["CloseTime"];
$ActionResult = $_POST["ActionResult"];
$Violation = $_POST["Violation"];
$ActionDetails = $_POST["ActionDetails"];
$Snags = $_POST["Snags"];
$SnagDesc = $_POST["SnagDesc"];
$Layout = $_POST["Layout"];
$LayoutDesc = $_POST["LayoutDesc"];
$CabinetLocation = $_POST["CabinetLocation"];
$Mapping = $_POST["Mapping"];
$MappingDesc = $_POST["MappingDesc"];
$Notes = $_POST["Notes"];

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Insert INTO DCO_Database (ActivityDate, CoreSite, ActionAuditor, DCOSPOC, AreaOwner, ActionImplementer, ActionOwner, MailSubject, ActionType, RequestType, RequestNumber, OpenTime, CloseTime, ActionResult, Violation, ActionDetails, Snags, SnagDesc, Layout, LayoutDesc, CabinetLocation, Mapping, MappingDesc, Notes) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssssssssssssss", $ActivityDate, $CoreSite, $ActionAuditor, $DCOSPOC, $AreaOwner, $ActionImplementer, $ActionOwner, $MailSubject, $ActionType, $RequestType, $RequestNumber, $OpenTime, $CloseTime, $ActionResult, $Violation, $ActionDetails, $Snags, $SnagDesc, $Layout, $LayoutDesc, $CabinetLocation, $Mapping, $MappingDesc, $Notes);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
else{
echo ("Failed");
$mysqli->close();    
}
echo ("Successful");
?>
```

Comment: You can't use where clause in INSERT query. I think you are looking for UPDATE!

Comment: It seems like the ``prepare`` method of the class object ``$mysqli`` (which by the way is defined nowhere in your code) is returning a falsy value. You may want to revisit that part, or paste code from the class that handles the database stuff.

Comment: An insert query should look like this `INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting data to table (mysqli insert)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835753/inserting-data-to-table-mysqli-insert)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

// think you should do as follows, insert statement only allows where clause when select statement is used,

```
<?php
$ActivityDate = $_POST["ActivitytDate"];
$CoreSite = $_POST["CoreSite"];
$ActionAuditor = $_POST["ActionAuditor"];
$DCOSPOC = $_POST["DCOSPOC"];

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Insert INTO DCO_Database (ActivityDate, CoreSite, ActionAuditor, DCOSPOC) values (?,?,?,?)");
{
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $ActivityDate, $CoreSite, $ActionAuditor, $DCOSPOC);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
else{
echo ("Failed");
$mysqli->close();    
}
?>
```

Comment: I updated the code and updated the post with values but still not working, check the edit if possible

Answer (score 2):

use **values** insted of **where**

```
<?php
 $ActivityDate = $_POST["ActivitytDate"];
 $CoreSite = $_POST["CoreSite"];
 $ActionAuditor = $_POST["ActionAuditor"];
  $DCOSPOC = $_POST["DCOSPOC"];

  if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Insert INTO DCO_Database (ActivityDate,  CoreSite, ActionAuditor, DCOSPOC) values(?,?,?,?)"))
  {

 $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $ActivityDate, $CoreSite, $ActionAuditor, $DCOSPOC);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();

 }
 else{
   echo ("Failed");
   $mysqli->close();    
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

> values

in your query. and remove

> AND

from the query too.  Please check the following code.

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Insert INTO DCO_Database (ActivityDate, CoreSite, ActionAuditor, DCOSPOC) values (?,?,?,?)"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $ActivityDate, $CoreSite, $ActionAuditor, $DCOSPOC);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
else{
echo ("Failed");
$mysqli->close();    
}
```

Please note that where is used for update. so to insert use the query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...) VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Comment: This is not a valid query.

Comment: thanks, I updated the code with values but still not working, would you please take a look on the code edit in the post

Comment: Solved, I was writing extra fetch commands caused the problem. many thanks