# Concatenate 'real_escape_string' add text before adding to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to add the word "Megapixels" after $_POST['mp'] so that within the 'mp' text box if I enter 12, it will save 12 Megapixels to the database.

PHP where I store the passed 'mp' value in the variable '$mp':

```
$mp = $cameras->real_escape_string($_POST['mp']);
```

I have tried the following

```
$mp = $cameras->real_escape_string($_POST['mp'] . "Megapixels");
$mp = $cameras->real_escape_string($_POST['mp']) . "Megapixels";
```

Im sure this would be very easy to do, I'm just missing something.

Thanks for your help

CODE UPDATE:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($add)) {
        /* GET FROM POST */
        $brand = $cameras->real_escape_string($_POST['brand']);
        $category = $cameras->real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
    $model = $cameras->real_escape_string($_POST['model']);
    $mp = $cameras->real_escape_string($_POST['mp']);
        /* QUERY */
        if (mysqli_query($cameras, "INSERT INTO models(
            /* ROW NAME */
            brand, category, model, mp

            ) VALUES(
            /* VARIABLE NAME */
            '$brand', '$category', '$model', '$mp'

            )")) {
            header("Location: http://admin.specced.co.uk?suc=3");
        } 
    }
?>
```

Comment: What isn't working? What is $cameras? statement? connection?

Comment: @SloanThrasher No I am able to add the passed value to the database, I just want to add "Megapixels" onto the end of it

Comment: Why not just use prepared statements, then you don't have to think about escaping the string.

Comment: I have thought of that, but there must be a way to add this on without prepared statements

Comment: Again, what isn't working with the code you show? Does the column in the table have the Megapixels or not? What is the column type? Is it a string type?

Comment: Of course there's a way without prepared statements, but then you are open to SQL injection.

Comment: No it doesn't have megapixels.... the column name is 'mp' I just want to add on "megapixels" when a value is inputted.... the type is a VARCHAR

Comment: @SloanThrasher this is a backend system so I'm not to worried, if there is a way, I would like to know

Comment: Show your code. The little bit you show should work, but that's based on a lot of presumptions about the code around it.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Thankyou, I have added the code chunk that adds the values into the DB

Comment: Based on your code, it should work unless there's a "special character" or something not shown in your question. I would use the 2nd form of the two you show. Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: "This is a backend system so I'm not to worried"... Be worried. This sort of casual dismissal is how you get into serious trouble. **Use prepared statements with placeholder values** like your life depends on it, because it just might. The internet is an extremely hostile place, and just because something's behind a password field doesn't mean it's secure. If you're not using prepared statements, someone can likely find a flaw in your code and bust through your login layer like it's not even there.

Comment: Thank you, but prepared statements is not going to allow me to concatenate into the end of the value is it ?

Comment: A) It **will**. Just bind to `$POST['mp'] . " Megapixels"` B) You should probably store things like "megapixels" in another column anyway. It's more convenient to operate on it when it's broken out as a unit-type field.

Comment: This is as simple as `$mp = $cameras->real_escape_string($_POST['mp']); 
$mp = $mp . "Megapixels";` and if that fails, then your HTML form failed.

Comment: btw `if (mysqli_query($cameras,` doesn't work that way; you need a db connection here, not a variable from your form's input. That's if `$cameras` isn't your db connnection and we don't know what that is. So this question is too unclear, IMHO. You should use naming conventions pertitent to a db connection, not an object.

Comment: *"prepared statements is not going to allow me to concatenate into the end of the value is it ?"* - Depends how it's done, and it can be done. @Bradley  - you'll need to @ me here if you want more help from me or if my other comment solved this; I feel it did.

Comment: *"so that within the 'mp' text box if I enter 12, it will save 12 Megapixels to the database."* - I don't know what you mean by that. Sorry, but your question is too unclear and I was about to post an answer but alas, decided not too. Stick with RamRaider's answer, I'll have to pass on this one.

Answer (score -1):

Before you process the `$_POST` array try changing the value of $_POST['mp']?

```
$_POST['mp'].='Megapixels';
$mp = $cameras->real_escape_string( $_POST['mp'] );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work and just causes the page to crash, no error shown.

Comment: Realy? Worked in a little test just now. The test was, in the form target of a particular form `$_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE'].='bananas';exit( $_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE'] );` which outputted `786432bananas` where `786432` was the permitted size ...

Comment: defiantly doesn't work for me, is there any other code I can show incase something else was causing it not to work ?

Comment: `$_POST['mp'].='Megapixels'; exit( print_r( $_POST ) );`

Comment: I just tried this and get the following : Array ( [brand] => 9 [category] => 52 [model] => ggg [mp] => gggggMegapixels [add] => Add ) 1

Comment: Maybe you cannot concatenate real_escape_string ?

Comment: looks like the value is being concatenated given the above data dump

Comment: Yes it is, possibly you cannot concatenate real_escape_string, I know I have the DB set up correctly as the mp row is a VARCHAR

Comment: `real_escape_string` just returns a string. It's not magical or special in any way.

Comment: @Bradley The array dump shows `gggggMegapixels`. Why would you think it isn't concatenated? The code is got to be failing for some error unrelated to string concatenation. Most likely with `mysqli_query()`. Please have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16835753/2298301) to write and execute a simple query first. And once that works, consider using _Prepared Statements_ - for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1290995) - as suggested in the comments above.