# Uploading data from form to MySQL Database

Tags: php

I am trying to upload data from a form to a MySQL Database and it is not working.

It just stays there and does nothing, and it does not insert into the database.

Please review my code below.

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        $query  = "INSERT INTO users (";
            $query .= "  first_name, last_name, username, password";
            $query .= ") VALUES (";
            $query .= " '{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$username}', '{$password}'";
            $query .= ")";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


        if($result) {
            echo "It worked";
        } else {
            echo "It did not work";
        }
        }   


?>
```

This is my html

```
           <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="white-box">
                        <form class="form-horizontal form-material" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-12">First Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="John" name="first_name" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-12">Last Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Doe" name="last_name" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-12">Username</label>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-12">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success">Create User</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Comment: Can you show me the code please?

Comment: what do you mean by "it is not working" ? does it make an error? does it insert new row but no values? , please be more descriptive about the problem

Comment: It does nothing it just stays the same and it does not insert a new row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting data to table (mysqli insert)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835753/inserting-data-to-table-mysqli-insert)

Comment: Which message is echoed ? "It worked" or "It did not work" ?

Comment: none of them are echoed.

Comment: try to echo $query and check if query is correct.

Comment: Can you show me the code

Comment: I do not understand.

Comment: @ShiylohBenFisher Then your PHP script is probably not executed at all, make `die('script is executed');` at the first line in your file and see what happens

Comment: show the content of print_r($_POST) above the if condition.

Comment: @Accountant The page is just keep on loading

Comment: @RavinderReddy this is what it does "Array ( )"

Comment: @RavinderReddy once i fill the form out it does this

Comment: Array ( [first_name] => Shiyloh [last_name] => mk; [username] => lm,;,; [password] => ;lm;l,;l )

Comment: you are checking $_POST['submit'] which is not set. since the condition failed, the code in if condition is not executed. Can you update the question with html form code

Comment: yes i can one second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are checking isset($_POST["submit"]), you need to add the input tag with type submit in your html form.

Replace

```
<button class="btn btn-success">Create User</button>
```

with

```
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create User">
```

Comment: It's working. Array ( [first_name] => sdffsdf [last_name] => fdfdf [username] => dfdfdf [password] => dfdf [submit] => Create User ) It worked

Comment: I can not upvote unless i get an upvote where i can upvote.

Comment: If you give @ShiylohBenFisher one more upvote he will be able to upvote your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = ($_POST['password']);



$query=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, username, password) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$username','$password')");
   if(!$query){
        die('could not enter data:'. mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    else{
        echo "Entered data successfully";
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: No it does not work and it still does not show a message.

Comment: @ShiylohBenFisher dont worry i will just send you whole code after correcting it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
            $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = md5($_POST['password']);

            $query  = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, password) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$username','$password')";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


            if($result) {
                echo "It worked";
            } else {
                echo "It did not work";
            }
        }   


?>
```

Comment: Did you replace"<button class="btn btn-success">Create User</button>" with <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create User"> and also <form class="form-horizontal form-material" action="NameOFphpFile" method="post">

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form  method="post" action="">

                                First Name

                                    <input type="text"  name="first_name" > 

                                Last Name

                                    <input type="text"  name="last_name" class="form-control form-control-line"> 

                                Username

                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" > 

                                Password

                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" > 
                         <input type="submit" name="update" value="create user">

                        </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    $host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";


$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysqli_select_db($conn,'db');            //database name is "db"
if (!$conn){
    die("could not create connection");
}
else
    echo"conection made <br>";
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = ($_POST['password']);



$query=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, username, password) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$username','$password')");
   if(!$query){
        die('could not enter data:'. mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    else{
        echo "Entered data successfully";
    }


}
?>
```