# Insert query inside if statement

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add the current date when a user is logged in on my system, however it doesn't seem to work!

```
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    $query = "  INSERT INTO accounts (last_login) VALUES (SYSDATE() 
    );WHERE `id`='".$id."'";
    header('Location: home.php');
```

The field last_login field in MySQL is set to datetime. Now what happens is that it redirects the user to home.php, however nothing is written in the DB!

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should resolve imminently

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this is on a test server! It's just for educational purposes!

Comment: IMO what environment it is doesn't matter, it's much more educational to do things the right way

Comment: As for the question itself... You're never actually executing your database query.  What database access technology are you using?  mysqli?  PDO?  Something else?  In the tutorials/examples for that technology there are demonstrations of how to execute a query.  Once you *execute* the query, you can then also check for errors from the database to see various things wrong with the query.

Comment: It is mysqli but what do you mean it is never executing? What should i do to insert it?

Comment: @Leonidas: You *define* the query, but all that does is create a string.  You need to *execute* the query in order to, well, execute it.  A Google search for "mysqli insert example" turns up the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835753/inserting-data-to-table-mysqli-insert  Note the line using `mysqli_query()`.  Note also the use of `mysqli_error()` to check for errors after executing the query, since you should never assume success but rather validate it.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note:

- I'd be surprised if you wanted to insert a record with only one value and no reference to the user account
- INSERT doesn't use a WHERE clause
- I'd expect you'd want to do an UPDATE
- Perhaps something like this:

  ```
  $query="UPDATE accounts SET last_login=NOW() WHERE id='".$id."'";
  ```

Answer (score -1):

You may use NOW() Function in your query it will return the current date and time like

```
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
$query = "  INSERT INTO accounts (last_login) VALUES (NOW()) WHERE id='$id'";
header('Location: home.php');
```