# jquery validate - remote always returns true

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a form and I am using jQuery validate plugin.

I am also using remote to check if the username and email are available or not but I always get false back from the script.

here is the jquery validation part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#registration').validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                email: true,
                remote:{
                    url: "./php/checkemail.php",
                    type: "POST",
                }
            },
            username: {
                minlength: 4,
                maxlength: 16,
                remote: {
                    url: "./php/checkusername.php",
                    type: "POST",
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    email: "Please enter a valid e-mail address.",
                    remote: "This email is already registered.",
                },
                username: {
                    minlength: "Your username must be at least 4 characters long but less than 16",
                    maxlength: "Your username must be at least 4 characters long but less than 16",
                    remote: "This username is already registered.",
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) { 
                    $('#registration').ajaxSubmit();
                    return false;
                },
            });
        });
```

and here is the checkemail.php file:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['email']));
    $check= mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER email = '$email'");
    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($check)!=0) {
        echo json_encode(false);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(true);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me please what I did wrong and how to fix it?

Also, even if I change the script to send me true, the remote message from the validation script doesn't appear on my form.

Comment: also, i have no errors in console

Comment: You should use your web browser's developers tools to check the return data from PHP. Even if you do not use Chrome this applies to all modern web browsers (IE8 and up lol) so check here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533285/why-the-ajax-script-is-not-running-on-iis-7-5-win-2008-r2-server#comment32640491_21533285

Comment: so it seams that i actually have a bunch of errors: 
mysqli_real_escape_string, mysqli_query, mysqli_stmt_num_rows - they all expect 2 parameters but only one is given. i checked the php documentation but if the $link part is the connection, then when i write that as the first parameter it tells me it's undefined

Comment: I recommend either updating your current question to focus on your mysqli issue or create a new question entirely. Leave AJAX (jQuery remote validation uses AJAX) out of it until your PHP's mysqli is resolved.

Comment: i solve it, apparently i have to wait 8 hours before i can post the answer.. but i will probably tomorrow. Thanks everyone for your help :)

Comment: If you would like I can just post my comment as an answer for this question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_query expects at least 2 parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073278/mysqli-query-expects-at-least-2-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I think the remote function is checking for a string.

So try this:

```
if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($check)!=0) {
    echo 'false';
} else {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that the php i used was deprecated and when i changed it to the new version i did it wrong... so the correct way of doing it is this:

> if(isset($_POST['email']))
>
> {
>
> $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
>
> $check= mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'") or die(mysqli_error($link));
>
> if(mysqli_num_rows($check)!=0)
>
> {
>
> ```
>   echo 'false';
> ```
>
> }else{
>
> ```
>   echo 'true';
> ```
>
> }
>
> }
>
> mysqli_close($link);
>
> ?>

where $link is the connection to the mysql database :

> $link = mysqli_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_password", "$db_database") or die ("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

and now it works just fine.