# Getting error when call mysql stored procedure from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have triggered the stored procedure from php. I have passed the input parameters also as shown.

```
$id = 1;
$nameDetail = 'raj';
$result = mysqli_query('CALL InsertDetails($id,$nameDetail)');
```

But getting below error.

```
mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given ...
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: are you connect database and host?

Comment: yes i connected database . SP has two parametes, i have passed two parameters also. But the error shows 1 given

Comment: `$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','dbname'); $mysqli->query("call InsertDetails($id,'$nameDetails')")` try this

Comment: Thanks for your reply. issue resolved. But the values not inserted in corresponding table.

Comment: show your store procedure

Comment: string variable should be in single or double quotes, like `'$name'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_query expects at least 2 parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073278/mysqli-query-expects-at-least-2-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're not set the mysqli connection.please try this

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','db');
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,'CALL InsertDetails($id,$nameDetail)');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have  $id = 1; $nameDetail= 'test'  ; $result = mysqli_query($connection,'CALL InsertDetails($id,$nameDetail)');. But the values not inserted in table.

Comment: Yes it working. SP triggered. But values not stored in table. this is my SP     CREATE PROCEDURE InsertDetails
(id int,
name varchar(100))
BEGIN
Declare newvalue varchar(50)
insert into student(id,Name) values(id,name);
set newvalue = 'success';
select newvalue;
END $$

Comment: wait let me check

Comment: change this, `insert into student (id, Name) values (sid, sname);`

Comment: run your store procedure to check,

Comment: @praveena- agree

Comment: @Gopal are you sure, your store procedure is execute successfully?

Comment: yes it was successfully executed. i can able to add value directly from SP . like CALL SP_name(1,'test'). But when i pass it from php it doesn't working,no errors found.

Comment: any other SP write before this SP

Comment: no,first SP in this database.I have one table and one SP in database for testing purpose.

Comment: $connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$id = 2;
$nameDetail = "venu";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection,'CALL InsertDetails($id,$nameDetail)'); This is in PHP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137510/discussion-between-praveena-and-gopal).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the connection as the first parameter:

```
// connect to DB
$connect = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

// run procedure
$result = mysqli_query($connect, 'CALL InsertDetails($id,$nameDetail)');
```