# Mysql refuses to connect

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$result = mysqli_query("query") or die('Cannot get product. ' . mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

I'm making a simple bank app in php, the database connects but I get the following errors on a particular page

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   /home/np9saef160p0/public_html/mybank/admin/account/detail.php on line
>   19
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   /home/np9saef160p0/public_html/mybank/admin/account/detail.php on line
>   19 Cannot get product.

Comment: We need to see that line 19!

Comment: looks like you are using mysqli_* functions as the old mysql_*. i see that because you are missing parameters.. i advice you to look into the PHP manual. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: $result = mysqli_query("query") or die('Cannot get product. ' . mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: Apologies if my question appears disjointed. I'm new here and still trying to get a hang of it

Comment: It is not possible to determine anything here because the shown code fails to meet the requirements for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), 
as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to read the help center, then edit your question, and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: **`mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given`** explain everything what is wrong here

Comment: you can't used  `mysqli_query("query")` because the syntax is: `mysqli_query(connection, query, resultmode);` in your example query is a string instead of a connection: `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","db_password_db","db_name");`
read this : https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_query expects at least 2 parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073278/mysqli-query-expects-at-least-2-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

you can't used `mysqli_query("query")` because the syntax is:

`mysqli_query(connection, query, resultmode);`

in your example "query" is a string instead of a connection:

`$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","db_password_db","db_name");`

read this : https://w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp