# mysqli query expects 2 parameter in portal

Tags: mysql

I am getting an error using the below code:

```
if($_POST['cmdLogin']=="Login")
{
    $txtUsername= $_POST['txtUsername'];
    $txtPassword= $_POST['txtPassword'];
    $database = "triumph";  
    //  Database Server Connection
    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","triumph","xxxx" );
    if(!link)
    {
        echo "Database connection error";
    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_select_db($link, $database);
    }

    $query="SELECT std_uname,std_pwd,std_status, login_state FROM user_regd where std_uname='$txtUsername'and std_pwd ='$txtPassword'";
    $result=mysqli_query($query);
```

Error is:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/triumph/xxxx/xxxx
```

Not sure what will be the possible solution here. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_query expects at least 2 parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073278/mysqli-query-expects-at-least-2-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use 
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
```